# Best practice to save the user's oauth_token and oauth_token_secret - Twitter API

Tags: php, twitter, oauth-2.0, twitter-oauth

I am creating a Twitter API application(using PHP libray Abraham\TwitterOAuth). when users authenticate the app I can get the oauth_token and oauth_token_secret for that user.
So now where to save those tokens for later use so that users don't have authenticate the app again and again.

### Can i save them in cookies ?

### UPDATE

@JánHalaša,
Hi, Thanks for your reply. I posted this question at three sites but not get any answer or comment So thanks:). Here is some more detail about the app.

I am using "PHP Abraham\TwitterOauth" Libray (uses Oauth2). My application have "read and write" permissions.  It gives users ability to mute or unmute any user. So here is whole process.

1. I ask user to signin, When user click on signin he asked to authenticate the app by Twitter.

2.Once he authenticate the app. He is redirected to callback url. Where i request the user's oauth_token and oauth_token_secret. And i store those tokens in cookies with little encryption. Some code from callback.php.

```
  $token = $connection->oauth(
'oauth/access_token', [
    'oauth_verifier' => $oauth_verifier
       ]
      );
 $token['oauth_token']=openssl_encrypt($token['oauth_token'],"AES-128-ECB",$salt);
 $token['oauth_token_secret']=
 openssl_encrypt($token['oauth_token_secret'],"AES-128-ECB",$salt);
 setcookie('oauth_token', $token['oauth_token'],time() + (86400 * 30));
 setcookie('oauth_secret', $token['oauth_token_secret'],time() + (86400 *30));
 header('location:'mute_now.php');
 die();
```

3.Now i redirect the users to a mute_now.php page. Where i decrypt these cookies and use the oath_token and oauth_secret to  get data from twitter on user's behalf. some_code from **mute_now.php** is

```
 $token['oauth_token'] = openssl_decrypt($_COOKIE['oauth_token'],"AES-128-ECB",$salt);
 $token['oauth_token_secret'] = openssl_decrypt($_COOKIE['oauth_token_secert'],"AES-128-ECB",$salt);

$twitter = new TwitterOAuth(
 $config['consumer_key'],
 $config['consumer_secret'],
 $token['oauth_token'],
 $token['oauth_token_secret']
);

$user_info = $twitter->get(
 "account/verify_credentials"
  );
$mutes = $twitter->get(
"mutes/users/list", ['include_entities'=>false,'skip_status'=>true]
  );
```

4. So now if user come to my website again. I check the cookie. And if cookies are  there . He don't need to authenticate the app again i directly redirect hime to mute_now.php and use those cookies to get oauth_token and oauth_token_secert

My main concern is about security. I know user can't use those tokens without the application credentials(consumer_key and consumer_secret). But i still concern about security. Should i use any encryption library like "defuse/php-encryption" before sending cookie.  Or any other suggestion Please?

Comment: When users pass OAuth2 authentication, they don't get any secret. You can keep access tokens in cookies, but the question is how you use them and what OAuth2 flow (authentication scenario) you use.

Comment: @JánHalaša. Hi, Thanks for your reply, I updated the question. Please let me know if you have any suggestions. :)